# multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'

Tags: serialization, multiprocessing, threadpool, bufferedreader, python-multiprocessing

I get the following error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f758760d6a0>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'
```

When running this code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from multiprocessing import Pool
import wget


def f(args):
    print(args[1])
    wget.download(args[1], "tests/" + target + '/' + str(args[0]), bar=None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Pool(2)
    a.map(f, list(enumerate(urls))) #urls is a list of urls.
```

What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows or Linux? Is this Python2.7 or 3.X?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 python3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '\_io.BufferedReader' object",)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736710/multiprocessing-pool-maybeencodingerror-typeerrorcannot-serialize-io-buffe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First couple of advices:

1. You should always check how well is project maintained. Apparently `wget` package is not.
2. You should check which libs is package using, in case something like this happens.

Now, to the issue.

Apparently `wget` uses `urllib.request` for making request. After some testing, I concluded that it doesn't handle all HTTP status codes. More specifically, it somehow breaks when HTTP status is, for example, `304`. This is why you have to use libraries with higher level interface. Even the `urllib.request` says this in official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

> The Requests package is recommended for a higher-level HTTP client interface.

So, without further ado, here is the working snippet.

You can just update with where you want to save files.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import shutil
import requests


def f(args):
    print(args)
    req = requests.get(args[1], stream=True)
    with open(str(args[0]), 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(req.raw, f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Pool(2)
    a.map(f, enumerate(urls))  # urls is a list of urls.
```

`shutil` lib is used for file manipulation. In this case, to stream the data to a file object.

Comment: this answer doesn't really explain why the error occurs

Comment: Without full stack trace and version of `wget` library, how can source of error be known? Also, there is no sufficient information to recreate the environment that was being used.