# How to fix "cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object" while multiprocessing?

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I get the following error when trying to parse a large number of web pages from a website : "Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'. How can I fix it ?

full error message is :

```
File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    records = p.map(defs.scrape,state_urls)
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x0000018DD1C3D828>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'
```

I browsed through some of the answers for similar questions here, namely this one ([multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: Reason: 'TypeError("cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object",)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761983/multiprocessing-pool-maybeencodingerror-error-sending-result-reason-typeerro)) but I don't think I'm running into the same issue, as I don't handle files directly in the scrape function.

I tried modifying the scrape function so it returned a string and not a list (don't know why I did that) but I didn't work.

From the main.py file :

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
from multiprocessing import Pool
import codecs
import defs
if __name__ == '__main__':

    filename = "some_courts_test.csv"
        # not the actual values
    courts = ["blabla", "blablabla", "blablabla","blabla"]

    client = defs.init_client()
    i = 1

    # scrapes the data from the website and puts it into a csv file
    for court in courts:
        records = []
        records_string =""
        print("creating a file for the court of : "+court)
        f = defs.init_court_file(court)
        print("generating urls for the court of "+court)        
        state_urls = defs.generate_state_urls(court)
        for url in state_urls:
            print(url)
        print("scraping creditors from : "+court)
        p = Pool(10)

        records = p.map(defs.scrape,state_urls)
        records_string = ''.join(records[1])
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
        for r in records_string:
            f.write(r)
        records = []

        f.close()
```

from the defs file:

```py
def scrape(url):
        data = []
        row_string = ' '
        final_data = []
        final_string = ' '
        uClient = uReq(url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        table = page_soup.find("table", {"class":"table table-striped"})
        table_body = table.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.replace(',',' ') for ele in cols] #cleans it up

            for ele in cols:
                if ele:
                    data.append(ele)
                data.append(',')
            data.append('\n')
        return(data)
```

Comment: The `io.BufferedReader` isn't a file handle, you are reading from a url in `uClient = uReq(url); page_html = uClient.read()` where `uClient` is the `io` object, and `read` is consuming the bytes data

Comment: Where is `uReq` defined? Are you using Windows? Typically windows does not play nice with multiprocessing due to the lack of `fork` system call and hence serialization problems when spawning the subprocesses... It seems like you should re-define `uReq` inside `scrape` to avoid this issue

Comment: uReq is imported from urllib.request, I haven't defined it myself. Yes I'm using windows. Is there something I can do or should I just try running it from another operating system ?

Comment: [multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: 'TypeError(“cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object”,)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54736710/9059420)